# Question incorrectly marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, reopen-request

I recently asked https://superuser.com/questions/930988/where-does-chrome-store-credit-card-data, which was closed by a moderator, stating that it's duplicate of [Google Chrome view saved form data](https://superuser.com/questions/224261/google-chrome-view-saved-form-data).

I wish to know how this questions would be duplicate, my question was about physical location of autoformfill data,but where as the op refered question was related to how to retrieve the stored data.

It's weird that it's marked as duplicate, can any one provide a solid reason how this would be duplicate of it? I marked/flagged the question for moderator attention, kindly clarify how it would be duplicate or kindly reopen the question.

Comment: Your question was not closed by a moderator, but by a regular community member.

Comment: And you had the wrong tag on it. The dup question was for Windows and you are asking about Linux. It seems the question has been reopened...

Answer (score 1):

That was me, and DavidPostill nailed it in his comment:

> you had the wrong tag on it. The dup question was for Windows and you are asking about Linux. It seems the question has been reopened...